# "Application failed to start"..."Field .... required a bean of type '...... that could not be found."

Tags: java, spring

I am creating a flight reservation application using Spring Tool Suite...I am getting the following error...

> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> Description:
>
> Field reservationService in 
>       com.siva.flightreservation.controllers.ReservationController required a 
>       bean of type 'com.siva.flightreservation.services.ReservationService' 
>       that could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> `@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)`
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 
>       'com.siva.flightreservation.services.ReservationService' in your configuration.

I have tried inject Reservation.service in to reservation controller....but don't know exactly how to do it...

This is my reservation controller file...

```
package com.siva.flightreservation.controllers;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import 
org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.siva.flightreservation.dto.ReservationRequest;
import com.siva.flightreservation.entities.Flight;
import com.siva.flightreservation.entities.Reservation;
import com.siva.flightreservation.repos.FlightRepository;
import com.siva.flightreservation.services.ReservationService;


@Controller
public class ReservationController {

@Autowired
FlightRepository flightRepository;


@Autowired

ReservationService reservationService;

@RequestMapping("/showCompleteReservation")
public String showCompleteReservation(@RequestParam("flightId") Long 
flightId, ModelMap modelMap) {
    Optional<Flight> flight = flightRepository.findById(flightId);
    if (flight.isPresent()) {
        modelMap.addAttribute("flight", flight.get());
    } else {
        // ERROR?
    }                   
    return "completeReservation";

}

 @RequestMapping(value="/completeReservation",method=RequestMethod.POST)    
 public String completeReservation(ReservationRequest request, ModelMap  modelMap) {

    Reservation reservation = reservationService.bookFlight(request);
    modelMap.addAttribute("msg", "Reservation created successfully and  the id is " + reservation.getId());
    return "reservationConfirmation";   
    }
}
```

This is my ReservationService Interface:

```
@Service

public class ReservationServiceImpl implements ReservationService {

@Autowired
FlightRepository flightRepository;

@Autowired
PassengerRepository passengerRepository;

@Autowired
ReservationRepository reservationRepository;

@Override
public Reservation bookFlight(ReservationRequest request) {

    Long flightId = request.getFlightId();
    Optional<Flight> flight = flightRepository.findById(flightId);

    Passenger passenger = new Passenger();
    passenger.setFirstName(request.getPassengerFirstName());
    passenger.setLastName(request.getPassengerLastName());
    passenger.setPhone(request.getPassengerPhone());
    passenger.setEmail(request.getPassengerEmail());
    Passenger savedPassenger = passengerRepository.save(passenger);

    Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
    reservation.setFlight(flight);
    reservation.setPassenger(savedPassenger);
    reservation.setCheckedIn(false);

    Reservation savedReservation = 
reservationRepository.save(reservation);

    return savedReservation;
    }
}
```

The ReservationConfirmation.jsp

```
`<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Reservation Confirmation</title>
</head>
<body>
${msg}
</body>
</html>`
```

and the Reservation class:
    `package com.siva.flightreservation.entities;

```
import java.util.Optional;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class Reservation extends AbstractEntity{

private Boolean checkedIn;
private int numberOfBags;
@OneToOne
private Passenger passenger;
@OneToOne
private Flight flight;


public Boolean getCheckedIn() {
    return checkedIn;
}

public void setCheckedIn(Boolean checkedIn) {
    this.checkedIn = checkedIn;
}

public int getNumberOfBags() {
    return numberOfBags;
}

public void setNumberOfBags(int numberOfBags) {
    this.numberOfBags = numberOfBags;
}

public Passenger getPassenger() {
    return passenger;
}

public void setPassenger(Passenger passenger) {
    this.passenger = passenger;
}

public Flight getFlight() {
    return flight;
}

public void setFlight(Flight flight) {
    this.flight = flight;
}

public boolean isPresent() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

public void setFlight(Optional<Flight> flight2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }
}
```

I was expecting the reservation info to get stored in the DB and a simple confirmation message along with id...thanks a lot

Comment: Check if your `ReservationServiceImpl` is picked up by your component scan

Comment: Could you also give as the class with main method?

Comment: Please add your component scan configuration as well as the `package` declaration for all relevant classes.

Comment: package com.siva.flightreservation;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.siva.flightreservation.controllers"})

public class FlightreservationApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(FlightreservationApplication.class, args);
 }

}

Comment: Hi Lino. I think ReservationServiceImpl is not picked up by the controller class and my component scan. How could it be fixed.